# Spring saml Extension with ADFS

Tags: spring-security, saml, adfs, spring-saml

I am working on integrating Spring saml Extension within ADFS for SSO. I am using ADFS2.0 as the IDP  and I have generated meta data for Spring application and imported meta data into ADFS. I will pass email address and display name to spring application.

Here is the claim rule I set in the ADFS.

## 1 get attributes

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";displayName,mail;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

## 2 Send email address as name ID

> c:[Type ==
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"] 
>   => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
>   Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value,
>   ValueType = c.ValueType,
>   Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"]
>   = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");

I can login in the Spring application. In General information, the information is correct. but in Principal's Attributes part. The value of attribute become org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyImpl@5abb6d06  and   org.opensaml.xml.schema.impl.XSAnyImpl@46f2d373.

Does anyone know why this happen? and how can I fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What version of Spring SAML are you using?

Comment: spring-security-saml-1.0.0.RC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update to *Spring SAML 1.0.0.RELEASE* (available in [Spring repos](http://repo.spring.io/list/release/org/springframework/security/extensions/)). The release contains helper methods which correctly handle string values in XSAny elements. See file `index.jsp` in the `sample` project for an example. The useful methods on `SAMLCredential` instances are:

```
String value = credential.getAttributeAsString("attributeName");
```

and

```
String[] value = credential.getAttributeAsStringArray("attributeName");
```

Comment: Thanks, I asked the service provider to upgrade their spring SAML extension. Now the value have been received correctly.

Comment: When will the project page (http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) be updated? There RC2 is still the current release.